# Does the Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud have a SQS Messaging Queue equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, message-queue, amazon-sqs, eucalyptus

I've stumbled upon Amazon's SQS offering, a messaging queue that's targeted at producer consumer solutions running in the cloud.

I'm attempting to build a proof of concept in my own private cloud for a larger solution that will run within the amazon cloud.

Does the Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud (Eucalyptus) provide an equivalent service to Amazon's SQS?

Does SQS conform to any sort of Messaging standard, so that I could use another open source implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No UEC does not provide extra services like a messaging/SQS. It seems SQS does not conform to messaging standards such as AMQP. If you would like to replace Amazon SQS with something faster and cheaper, check out this article
http://notes.variogr.am/post/67710296/replacing-amazon-sqs-with-something-faster-and-cheaper

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the old good onlinemq (message queuing platform) for this purpose